# How to insert multiple rows to a table without using for loop in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I have 2 tables: `questions` and `mcq_choices`. When I insert a row to the questions table, with a trigger function, I want to insert 1 or more rows to the `mcq_choices` table without using a for loop at the insertion. `doc_id` from `questions` table and `question_id` from `mcq_choices` table will the foreign key.

To prepare the data that I will insert to choices table, I've created a function that takes in `mcq_choices` (jsonb []) and `question_id` (text) as arguments, which already exist in questions table. I want this function to return setof jsonb[] or json[][], or whatever will make it easy to use at the moment of insertion inside the trigger function.

How should I change both the function and the trigger function?

The trigger function `insert_to_mcq_choices` (runs when a row is inserted to `questions` table) looks like this:

```
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO public.mcq_choices (
        question_id,
        choice_id,
        content
    )
    SELECT * FROM public.create_choices_rows(NEW.mcq_choices, NEW.doc_id);-- what should this line be like?
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Here is the function `create_choices_rows` (currently returns `setof jsonb`):

```
DECLARE
    choice jsonb;
    arr jsonb[];
BEGIN
    FOR choice IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(choices)
    LOOP
        arr := ARRAY[
            doc_id,
            (choice->'question_id')::jsonb,
            (choice->'choice_id')::jsonb,
            (choice->'content')::jsonb,
        ];

        RETURN NEXT arr;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: I would not use a trigger.  Since you are already passing the question and choices information when inserting into the question table, do that insert and the inserts to the choices table in a single SQL statement.